# How can I specify a special character in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, fusioncharts

I am trying to output a sigma character (σ) in a label in a FusionChart graph.  How can I specify that character in a PHP string?  I have tried the htmlentity `&sigma;`, but it is not interpreted correctly by the graph.  Is there any way to specify the character in PHP using some sort of character code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you're sending the correct headers when outputting.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

$char = utf8_encode(html_entity_decode('&sigma;'));

echo $char;
```

This will output the character.

**Edit**:

If passing the character into the graph doesn't work, then the software doesn't support UTF-8.

Comment: I thought this was going to work.  Unfortunately, I still get &sigma; output, no matter how I manage to structure the header.

Comment: According to FusionCharts documentation and example graphs, they do support Unicode

Comment: I can get it output correctly to the browser using this answer, however I am clearly not specifying it correctly in setting up the xml for the chart.

Comment: Yes, encoding can be a mine field, eh?  My rule of thumb is to make everything UTF-8.  Googling or just searching on this site will provide plenty of resources on that topic.

Answer (score 2):

`"\x1F"` will work for regular ASCII characters, but I think sigma is a unicode character, so you're going to have to use something like [utf8_encode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php). PHP has poor Unicode support.

Answer (score 2):

The sigma (σ) can be represented in UTF-8 encoding by the byte sequende `xCF x83` (codepoint U+03C3), so you could try to build a PHP string

```
$sigma = "\xCF\x83";
```

<del>But as I don't know FusionChart, I cannot say if it can handle UTF-8 encoded strings or multi-byte strings in general.</del> According to their product description, they do support unicode (**but require a UTF-8 BOM**), so you can build the XML response in PHP:

```
$response = "\xEF\xBB\xEF<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>
<root>
    <element attribute=\"\xCF\x83\">\xCF\x83</element>
</root>";
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'); 
echo $response;
```

<del>There is also a sigma (σ) character in ISO-8859-7 and Windows-1253 (`xF3`) - but I doubt that this will help you.</del>

<del>Third option would be to specify some kind of mathematical symbol font that maps the sigma (σ) to some other character.</del>

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
html_entity_decode('&sigma;');
```

[PHP Manual for html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

Comment: Tried it, but it output &sigma;

Answer (score 1):

I could use chr(229) as well, where 229 is the ASCII code I'm looking for

Comment: The Extended ASCII table I found was wrong.  There is no sigma in ASCII

Answer (score 1):

For FusionCharts, to show small sigma in the chart, please use %CF%83. Put this percentage encoded form in a php string. 
I have tried this. It works. Also check the documentation pages on using special characters here: http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/Contents/SpChar_Euro.html
http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/Contents/SpChar_Pound.html
etc.

Answer (score 1):

Save your .php file as utf-8 encode with bom enabled,and you can use directly a sigma character (σ).

```
    $sXML = "<chart><set value='20' label='σ' /></chart>";
echo renderChartHTML("../FusionCharts/Column2D.swf", "", "$sXML", "myFirst", 600, 300, false);
```